# How to set redirect uri of youtube data api

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-data-api

I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) and done everything mentioned there.

But when I run I get the code error: redirect_uri_mismatch.

It is not picking the redirected uri which is located inside client_secret.json.

I have not changed a single line from the sample code they have provided.

Instead of this solution, I have tried with simple https oauth process that works fine but with client library it is not working.

Code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace youtubeapiweb.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: retrieve my uploads.
    /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
    /// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
    /// </summary>
    internal class MyUploads
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: My Uploads");
            Console.WriteLine("============================");

            try
            {
                new MyUploads().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;


            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\users\noman nawaz\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\youtubeapiweb\youtubeapiweb\Models\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
                // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                    // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                        // Print information about each video.
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                    }

                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result would be the google auth screen where user has complete its authorization and the response sends back to redirected uri.

Comment: Without including your actual client secrets, could you share the layout of your client_secrets.json file?

Comment: sure {
  "web": {
    "client_id": "xyz",
    "project_id": "xyz",
    "auth_uri": "xyz",
    "token_uri": "xyz",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xyz",
    "client_secret": "xyz",
    "redirect_uris": [ "xyz" ],
    "javascript_origins": [ "abc", "xyz" ]
  }
}

Comment: this is the redirected link generated by the code i have shared, you can see it adds redirect uri ====>  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A4238%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly
actual redirect_uri which is written in client_secret.json is http://localhost:37783/home/contact

Comment: Did you add your redirect URI to the list of authorized redirect URIs in the Google API console?

Comment: Yes i did, its working fine when i directly use https instead of .net client library

Comment: @nouman you last comment is the solution to your problem, right?, if so, please consider [post and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no that wasn't the answer that solution worked when we use http methods instead of client library, for client library i was using wrong redirect_uri for localhost, which i had found inside github answers, i dont remember that link